# Thinking sphinx: multiple delta indices on single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, resque, thinking-sphinx

I have several questions about delta indexing when a model's index is separated into multiple indices.

In this example:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :model, name: "index_1", with: :active_record, delta: ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::ResqueDelta do
    indexes :field_a
end

ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :model, name: "index_2", with: :active_record, delta: ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::ResqueDelta do
    indexes :field_b
end
```

I get these files for each index:

```
model_index_1_delta
model_index_2_delta
model_index_1_core
model_index_2_core
```

1. If I update a record on `field_a`, will `model_index_2_delta` also get updated?
2. If both `field_a` and `field_b` are updated on a record:

   a. Will a re-index update both `model_index_1_core` and `model_index_2_core` simultaneously?

   b. When will the record's delta field be set to 0 in the DB?

   c. Will one of the core files not get updated correctly if the delta field was set to 0 already by a previous re-index run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, if you update field_a, both deltas will be updated. Thinking Sphinx does not try to figure out whether model changes are relevant to a specific index.
2. a. It depends on how deltas are processed. If it's the default delta
   processor (`:delta => true`), then they're processed one after the
   other. You're using Resque, so the processing of each index could
   indeed overlap. That's fine, though.

   b. The delta flag is only set to false/zero when a full index happens via the `rake ts:index` task, and only set to true/one by delta processing. It remains set to true until the rake task is run - it's an indication of whether there are changes not present in core (rather than an indication that it just needs to be processed for the delta index).

   c. The core indices load *all* data when `rake ts:index` is run - there is no filter on the delta column.

Comment: Thanks. About question 2.b: so there should be no problem having one 'delta' column for multiple indices on a model? I.e., one index won't set the flag to false and prevent another index from updating?

Comment: The only time that might happen is when `rake ts:index` is running - as it processes the first core index, then marks delta to false for all records, then processes first delta index, then processes second core index, then processes second delta index. Sphinx reloads all index files at once (by default), so the changes would all be applied together...

Comment: ... but I guess it's possible that a delta processor marks a record's delta to true *while* that rake task is running, and then the indexer marks it back to false before the delta processor has time to run just the delta index. We're talking milliseconds, though, for such a collision.